# Update column in one table with values from different table without adding new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables and one common column named code in both the tables. I want to update the values of a column named version in table A with column named set_version values in table B.But this should not add rows and only update values. How do I do that?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: An `UPDATE` does what it say, it **updates** the data. if you want new data, you want an `INSERT` statement. If you do need to do both, in same statement, you want `MERGE`.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `update` with `join`:

```
update a
    set version = b.set_version
    from a join
         b
         on <some join condition here that your question does not specify>;
```

The `update` only updates existing rows.  It does not add new rows to the table.

Comment: will this add a new row? or will it just reflect those rows where my condition matches?

Comment: no, it won't add any new rows, since no insert command were issued. It will only update rows where joining criteria is matched. If there are no matching rows, there will be no updates at all.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers were correct.But to make it more perfect I would like to answer my question so that if anyone reads then he/she should get it in one glance....

What I have :

There are two tables 'A' and 'B' with one common column 'Code'

What I want :

- Put the values in the column named 'Version' of table 'A' from the column named 'Set_version' of table 'B.
- And there is a common column between table 'A' and 'B' named 'Code'.
- Only if the values match in the common columns then only impact the rows of the column named 'Version' in table 'A' with values in 'Set-version' of table 'B' without adding new rows in the table.If there are no rows matching then there should be no impact.

Solution:

Structure in general

```
UPDATE        targetTable
SET           targetTable.targetColumn = s.sourceColumn
FROM          targetTable t
INNER JOIN    sourceTable s
ON            t.matchingColumn = s.matchingColumn
```

Structure using my table and coumn names

```
UPDATE        dbo.A
SET           dbo.A.Version = s.Set_version
FROM          dbo.A t
INNER JOIN    dbo.B s
ON            t.Code = s.Code
```

This will definitely help the one with my scenario!